# Create a multiboot flash drive for Windows using Yumi app

Tags: flash, iso, yumi

I want to create a multi-boot flash drive for Windows, using only the Yumi app.

Is it mandatory for me to add Ubuntu ISO to create my multi-bootable flash drive even when I don't need Ubuntu?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Or are you using Windows?

Comment: You do not need an app when creating a Windows installer USB. Just extract the Windows ISO to an 8GB+ USB that is formatted NTFS. To install Windows boot the USB using UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to add an Ubuntu ISO to create a multiboot flash drive using the YUMI multiboot USB creator application.